# Celery: correct way to run lengthy initialization function (per process)

Tags: python, initialization, multiprocessing, celery, python-c-extension

**TLDR;**

To run an initialization function for each process that is spawned by celery, you can use the `worker_process_init` signal. As you can read in the [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#worker-process-init), handlers for that signal should not be blocking for more than 4 seconds.
But what are the options, if I have to run an init function that takes more than 4 seconds to execute?

**Problem**

I use a C extension module to run certain operations within celery tasks. This module requires an initialization that might take several seconds (maybe 4 - 10). Since I would rather prefer not to run this init function for every task but for every process that is spawned, I made use of the `worker_process_init` signal:

```
#lib.py 
import isclient #c extension module
client = None
def init():
    global client
    client = isclient.Client() #this might take a while

def create_ne_list(text):
    return client.ne_receiventities4datachunk(text)

#celery.py
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import worker_process_init
from lib import init

celery = Celery(include=[
    'isc.ne.tasks'
])

celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

@worker_process_init.connect
def process_init(sender=None, conf=None, **kwargs):
    init()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery.start()

#tasks.py
from celery import celery
from lib import create_ne_list as cnl

@celery.task(time_limit=1200)
def create_ne_list(text):
    return cnl(text)
```

What happens, when I run this code is what I described in my earlier question ([Celery: stuck in infinitly repeating timeouts (Timed out waiting for UP message)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201066/celery-stuck-in-infinitly-repeating-timeouts-timed-out-waiting-for-up-message)). In short: since my init function takes longer than 4 seconds, it sometimes happens that a worker gets killed and restarted and during the restarting process gets killed again, because that's what automatically happens after 4 seconds unresponsiveness. This eventually results in an infinite repeating kill-and-restart process.

Another option would be to run my init function only once for every worker, using the signal `worker_init`. If I do that, I get a different problem: Now the queued up processes get stuck for some reason. 
When I start the worker with a concurrency of 3, and then send a couple of tasks, the first three will get finished, the remaining ones won't get touched. (I assume it might have something to do with the fact, that the `client` objects needs to be shared between multiple processes and that the C extension, for some reasons, doesn't support that. But to be honest, I'm relatively new to muli-processing, so I can just guess)

**Question**

So, the question remains: How can I run an init function per process that takes longer than 4 seconds? Is there a correct way to do that and what way would that be?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate [of your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201066/celery-stuck-in-infinitly-repeating-timeouts-timed-out-waiting-for-up-message)?

Comment: @Veedrac it's not at all? How should it be a duplicate? It's more of a follow-up question.

Comment: I think on later reading I get the difference. The problem really is that neither post has a clear problem statement, so it's not obvious what answers are wanted.

Comment: @Veedrac good point. I edited this question and hope it is now a bit clearer what I'm asking.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a subclassed task class will run its __init__ function once per process. You should be able to put your long init function in there. You'll have to refactor a bit and add `base=YourTaskSubclass` to the task decorator.

Answer (score 13):

Celery limits to process init timeout to 4.0 sec.
Check [source code](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/72b16ac7c43c9cbd56d2cc9d87ba5552d159ef1e/celery/concurrency/asynpool.py#L86)

To workaround this limit, you can consider change it before you create celery app

```
from celery.concurrency import asynpool
asynpool.PROC_ALIVE_TIMEOUT = 10.0 #set this long enough
```

Note that there is no configuration or setting to change this value.

Answer (score 8):

[@changhwan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3451543/changhwan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31469099/4785629) is no longer the only method as of celery 4.4.0. Here is the [pull request](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/5476) that added the config option for this feature.

## Use the config option

With celery `^4.4.0`, this value is configurable. Use the celery application config option `worker_proc_alive_timeout`. From the [stable version docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#worker-proc-alive-timeout):

> **worker_proc_alive_timeout**
>
> *Default: 4.0.*
>
> The timeout in seconds (int/float) when waiting for a new worker process to start up.

### Example:

```py
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import worker_process_init

app = Celery('app')
app.conf.worker_proc_alive_timeout = 10

@worker_process_init.connect
def long_init_function(*args, **kwargs):
   import time
   time.sleep(8)
```